# How big are the armv6 and armv7 architectures?

Tags: xcode, armv7, armv6

When I submitted my app for review I got and email saying in processing, my app size jumped from 14mb to 34mb. That is huge and totally unfair!

I assume that this was all due to the arm architectures. But, how can they be that big? That means it is impossible to go under the 3g limit.

Is something wrong with my logic? And, how big are the arm architectures?

Comment: More than likely retina/ipad assets making the size increase.  And the architecture logic won't matter that much as that is mostly on device stuff anyway.  Other than that, I'm not too sure what you're asking.

Comment: I got that bit, but the difference in architectures should only result in a SLIGHT increase in binary size.  Your question is rather broad though, which was more what I was getting at.

Comment: For such a jump in size, it is likely asset related. The architecture size, is most likely a red herring.

Comment: I had a 20+ mb audio file, but I converted it to mp3. Maybe THAT got uncompressed? I converted it with itunes. Could that be the problem? None of my other assets are 1 mb+ If the arm architectures dont add much, then the audio must be the problem.

Comment: Those uncompressions couldn't be done by Apple as it would make your signing invalid.

Comment: Why would the size increase after proccessing though?

Comment: When you send it, you are sending a ZIP (compressed) file. Which must be unzipped at the other end. Maybe it compresses Down to a 17mb ZIP, but it's actually around the 34mb mark unzipped?

Comment: I guess, but I looked over my assets, and I have 2 mb of textures. 4 mb of dlls, and 1 mb of compressed audio (used to be 20). So why did it end up that big? Are you sure the arm architectures are big?

Comment: What size is the built product on the file-system?

Comment: You mean the archive file? 14mb.

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://www.indiepinion.com/steffenj/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-an-iphone-app-after-approval/

Comment: Yes, but this does't tell me why the problem exists, it just tells me how to calculate app size.

Comment: It also shows more evidence that Unity Apps **are hit pretty severely by the loss of compression due to the encryption process**, 4-5 MB was what most users reported with some even much more than that.  Does that not cover it? (It's in the first paragraph!)

Comment: I got it now, more research showed that others had similar problems. Apples compression system essentially doubles your app file size! Anyways, thanks for the help really appreaciate it. Feel free to write an answer for rep/karma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the encryption process at Apple's end, compression of the data can be severely hit (particulary if using Unity).

See this post for details: http://www.indiepinion.com/steffenj/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-an-iphone-app-after-approval/